# Why is VSCode latex snippet not working (// character)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I want to have create the following snippets:

```
    "fraction": {
            "prefix": ["//"],
            "body": [
                "\\frac{$1}{$2}",
            ],
            "description": "Fraction"
        },
```

I have many snippets in my latex.json file and all seem to work fine but this one doesn't, any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me.  What happens when you type `//` ?  Do you get the suggestion box conteining the `fraction` name?

Comment: @Mark hm it just didn't work. A related question: `=>` as a snippet also doesn't work for me even though I want to map it to implies, does this work for you?

Comment: @Mark and no, I'm not getting a suggestion box.